# upload file to amazon cloud subfolder using python boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm writing some python script and I am trying to upload a file to the amazon cloud using boto3. The problem is I want to upload the file to a particular subfolder...in some cases I will need to upload the file to a subfolder of a subfolder.

I'm trying to do this:

```
s3.meta.client.upload_file( "C:\\Users...\\folder1" + "\\" + someFile.txt, "folder/subfolder1/subfolder2", someFile.txt)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Invalid bucket name "...": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9. \-]{1,255}$"
```

It works if I just do folder, but not if I try to do `folder/subfolder1/subfolder2`.

I tried to understand it with the documentation but could not.  Can someone please explain it to me?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The second parameter to your `s3.meta.client.upload_file()` call should be the **bucket name**, not a file path ([reference](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.upload_file)):

```
s3.meta.client.upload_file( "C:\Users...\folder1" + "\" + someFile.txt, "your-bucket-name", "someFile.txt")
```

As for folders, you must determine the folder structure using the `key` (the 3rd param in `upload_file()`) parameter:

```
s3.meta.client.upload_file( "C:\Users...\folder1" + "\" + someFile.txt, "your-bucket-name", "some_folder/some_subfoler/someFile.txt")
```